# What will my academic path look like after testing out of high school math classes?

Tags: mathematics, united-states

I am currently a 15-year-old in the 9th grade, and I am studying to test out all of my high school math classes, which is something I didn't realize I could do in the 8th grade and would have if I had. I contacted faculty, and if all goes well, I'll test out of Geometry, Algebra II, Precalculus, and AP Calculus BC. I also hope that once at college, I can test out of Linear Algebra.

I have also been studying Japanese for a few years, and know the meaning of all the required Jōyō Kanji, although I lack vocabulary otherwise. Because of this background, I plan to Major in Pure Mathematics, and Minor in Japanese Studies.

If I end up taking classes at Delta, (a nearby community college) I would not be able to take Topology, Complex Analysis, Real Analysis, or Abstract Algebra. Instead, I would take Multivariable Calculus, Linear Algebra (if I fail to test out of it), and an ODE course, as Delta only has a Transfer Math program, and no Japanese language program.

I've been told that my high school will also pay for my college classes while enrolled in high school, although the only people they have ever done this for went to Delta during high school, and they were seniors in the 12th grade.

That being said, I have a few general questions about college that that fall under the umbrella of the title.

- Would it make sense to apply for colleges as anything other than a Senior, or dual enroll in non-community colleges?
- What will writing a thesis be like for someone with no Math paper writing experience?
- I have below-average grades in everything but Math, how much will this affect me?
- As a high school freshman, I've yet to take the SAT, how much will this affect me?
- For the math people reading this, how do you recommend studying math on my own?
- My mother doesn't want me to test out of my math classes, because "they teach me hard work,"
  and because she wants me to raise my other grades first before doing something "fun". How do I deal with that?

Comment: Watch out for your overall GPA. Dual enrollment programs often have a minimum GPA requirement--because the thought is that if you're not successful in all your classes, adding a college-level course is a burden. FYI, this stackexchange is for graduate students, lecturers, professors, not for undergraduate or high school students. Your question is likely to be closed shortly. You may want to take the [tour]. For Japanese, try Duolingo or look into doing an intensive summer program.

Comment: This question is manifestly not about "undergrad" math (whatever that means, and many meanings are, in my opinion, foolish)... since it is exactly about a young person who is not waiting passively to learn/do mathematics. I myself had a vaguely similar arc, and have some hopefully-useful comments which I will write out tomorrow. I do seriously hope that people will not belittle/downvote/whatever this question... The extreme disconnect of timing about math versus other subjects, and parents' expectations, etc., is a genuine issue for some kids. More later.

Comment: If you can get a passing grade on the AP Calculus BC class while you are in 9th grade, you would probably be successful in an early college.  I recommend http://simons-rock.edu.  If you have reasonable writing ability, you would be likely to get a full scholarship.  Community colleges are not designed for students who are ~5 years ahead of average.

Comment: My mother doesn't want me to test out of my math classes, because "they teach me hard work," Testing out of math classes and taking more advanced math classes would be harder, not easier.  Study for and get a good score on the AP tests.  While standardized tests are bad, they do at least demonstrate that you can work hard.

Comment: Whatever you do, please keep in mind that there are many other things one needs in order to become a healthy and happy person besides studying and career. Please don't forget to constantly improve your social skills (however good they may be now) and develop new hobbies, be interested in the world.

Comment: Be careful not to confuse being good at tests with actually understanding the topic. Either is possible without the other, but while being good at tests is the important thing until maybe late undergrad, it is an entirely useless skill afterwards. As knowledge in mathematics is quite cumulative, lack of understanding can result in you being far behind quite suddenly. You seem to have already diagnosed that problem in your Japanese, so be on the lookout for the same in maths. In short, don't be the maths equivalent of the guy who knows all kanji, but isn't able to form any coherent sentence.

Comment: I highly recommend the Art of Problem Solving. https://artofproblemsolving.com/

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist Not even; I wouldn't say I worked particularly hard on my AP tests and passed them all.